# Javascript (NOT jQuery) ..calling the OnClick event of an <a> anchor

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an anchor somewhere and need to call it's `onclick` event programmatically from JavaScript. The site does not have jQuery.

The solution needs to be "cross-browser"

I tried:

```
document.getElementById('anchorID').onclick();
```

or

```
document.getElementById('anchorID').click();
```

but nothing gets fired.

Comment: Possible duplication of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2490825/1370576

Comment: Since it's an ASP.NET page can't you just use code behind to handle the onClick() event?

Answer (score 0):

you can try raiseEvent, but I am not sure if it is cross-browser.